# Test coverage tool for Behave test framework

Tags: python, automated-tests, coverage.py, python-behave

We are using Behave BDD tool for automating API's. Is there any tool which give code coverage using our behave cases?

We tried using coverage module, it didn't work with Behave.

Answer (score 18):

You can run any module with coverage to see the code usage.
In your case should be close to `coverage run --source='.' -m behave`

Tracking code coverage for Aceptace/Integration/Behaviour test will give a high coverage number easily but can lead to the idea that the code are properly tested.

Those are for see things working together, not to track how much code are well 'covered'.

Tying together unittests and coverages makes more sense to me.

Comment: Code coverage for behavior tests may not mean the same thing as code coverage for unit tests, but it is still informative and useful: it tells you how much of your code is actually used by your users.  In other words, if code coverage for behavior tests is quite low, it means you're writing way too much code...

Comment: @AndréCaron It might also mean that either your tests are deficient or that  there are not enough of them. </pedantic>